# Tensorflow model fails to load more than once

Tags: tensorflow

I have used tensorflow to train a CNN model to do character classification. I have saved my best model using a tf.train.Saver() object. To do classification in an application, i use a function as can be seen below.

```
def classify_chars(images):
    # Create the model
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 400])

    # Build the graph for the deep net
    y_conv, keep_prob = _deepnn(x)

    # Define classification
    letter_class = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)
    confidence = tf.reduce_max(tf.nn.softmax(y_conv), 1)

    # Enable saving and loading of variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Restore variables from disk.
        saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(M_PATH, "char_model.ckpt"))
        print("Model restored.")

        images_classes = letter_class.eval(feed_dict={x: images})
        images_confidences = confidence.eval(feed_dict={x: images})

    return images_classes, images_confidences
```

This function loads the saved model and uses it to classify the function input. The function works exactly as intended when called once. However, if I call it more than once during the same execution, it fails, throwing:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Variable_9 not found in checkpoint
```

Now, if this happened whenever the function was used, this would make sense to me, and I would assume there probably was something wrong with my model saving. But here it seems more like the function has state that persists outside of it, that prevents a second run. When looking at my code, however, I fail to see what this state could be. I do not overwrite my checkpoint file, so in theory, there should not be anything wrong with the loading of it.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem resulted from not resetting the default graph between function calls. It TensorFlow already has a graph, trying to load the same graph again results in this error. This can be mitigated by adding

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

before the restoring of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

tf.saver adds the global step to checkpoint name, may be you should check if that's the problem

Comment: Not sure I understand how that can be problematic?

Comment: in your checkpoints folder a file named checkpoint is automatically created by tensorflow which has the following entries 
model_checkpoint_path and
all_model_checkpoint_paths 
try to get model path from there using 
saver.restore(session, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)